# Regarding Entering Key in LPush

Tags: redis

When the key contains `-` in the key, i.e.

```
e: = conn.LPush("6cd3b647-0a9d-4119-6438-07a9dda1bc7f", json)
```

it gives:

> WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of
>   value

Answer (score 2):

The 'WRONGTYPE' error means that the key already has a value but of another type. In your case, the key isn't a list so you can `LPUSH` into it.

You can find the key's type with the `TYPE` command. If you want to create a list in that key, first `DEL` the existing one.

Comment: Thanks Itamar Haber that solved the problem, earlier I inserted the same key of type Set